Graph API : How can I get Sharepoint webhook resourceData Id?
I'm currently working on webhook notification for SharePoint Online drive using MS Graph API. The subscription is already setup as bellow.
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions

{
    "changeType": "updated",
    "notificationUrl": "https://a123bluhbluh.ngrok-free.app/api/WebHook",
    "resource": "/drive/root",
    "expirationDateTime": "2024-07-01T00:00:00Z",
    "clientState": "c9a46c1f-9d7d-4e2b-80d3-4b18a0d0d4ae"
}

Whenever I make any change in the drive by adding/deleting a file I get a notification but the resourceData is null (I only get OdatType).
{"value":[
   {"subscriptionId":"XXX",
      "clientState":"c9a46c1f-9d7d-4e2b-80d3-4b18a0d0d4ae",
      "tenantId":"XXX",
      "resource":"drives/root",
      "resourceData":{
          "@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Graph.DriveItem",
          "Id" : null,
          "ODataEtag" : null,
          "ODataId" : null
       },
      "changeType":"updated",
      "subscriptionExpirationDateTime":"2024-07-01T00:00:00Z"
    }
  ]
}

I also tried adding "includeResourceData": true to my subscription but failed (It seems like includeResourceData is not vaild for sharepoint).
I really need file(item) ID for other function. Everyone Please help me!!

Not all resources return resourceData within the notification itself and driveItem is one of these.
To find out details about updated items you will have to use delta query.
Let's say you have a subscription for /me/drive/root and you have the latest delta link for /me/drive/root.
Once you receive notification about a change, you will use the query from the delta link like this
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/delta?token={token}

The response will contain details about updated drive items.
